# combine one line statements into a single script

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to get 3 separate single line commands to run one after the other, but am unable to get this to work if they are all in the same shell.sh file.

```
awk 'Command #1 1' input.txt > output.txt
awk 'Command #2 1' input.txt > output.txt
awk 'Command #3 1' input.txt > output.txt
```

Above is an example of what I will have in shell.sh, and I am only able to achieve this using 3 separate files, when I need these to all work in a single file.

In my example I want a single input file to have 3 commands run against it to produce a single output file.

I am not sure if I am able to combine using `>>`, `|`, or `&&`, but all tries have given poor results.

Comment: Define "poor results"?

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried using the answer given for example, and the second command overwrites the output so the data from the first command is gone... and when I change the input for command #2 to represent output from command 1 the new output is 0kb

Comment: Then you need Avinash Raj's answer. And you can't `command file > file` because the shell truncates the output file before the command runs so it sees a blank input file.

Comment: @EtanReisner Even this will not work. When I use Avinash Raj's method the file is overwritten each time. The commands change the source file, so I cannot read back to the original each time, I need read the new information after each command run

Comment: Ah, you need them to operate on the output of the previous script? Then that is tripleee's answer (and you should have made this clear in the beginning that was, ultimately, my point).

Comment: You MUST provide sample input and expected output and a better description of what you want the 3 awk commands to do or you stand an excellent chance of getting an answer that produces the output you expect but is a completely ridiculous way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is overwriting the output file from each previous command, so it will appear as if only the last command succeeded.

If you want to run three Awk scripts in succession, you are looking for a pipeline.

```
awk 'Command #1 1' input.txt |
awk 'Command #2 1' |
awk 'Command #3 1' > output.txt
```

But of course, you probably want to combine them into a single script.

```
awk 'Command #1
     Command #2
     Command #3 1' input.txt> output.txt
```

Unfortunately, your question is too general to provide actual specific advice on whether this is feasible and useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the output redirection operator `>>`

```
awk 'Script #1 1' input.txt > output.txt
awk 'Script #2 1' input.txt >> output.txt
awk 'Script #3 1' input.txt >> output.txt
```